# How might I save the the output of "find .... -execdir ..." to a log?

Tags: find, io-redirection

I cannot get the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

/usr/bin/find ~/CS -iname "*.html.pmd" -type f -execdir /usr/bin/raco pollen render {} \; > ~/rendering
```

to redirect the output to the file `~/rendering` although when I run it from my shell it spits out a lot of output on the screen. The script does create empty `~/rendering` file, though. How might I save the output in a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does redirect *stdout* to the file `~/rendering`. If you're still seeing output sent to the screen then it's likely it's being written to *stderr* (standard error).

Append `2>&1` to the end of the command to send the *stderr* stream (#2) to the same place as *stdout* (#1).

Comment: Thanks, `/usr/bin/find ~/CS -iname "*.html.pmd" -type f -execdir /usr/bin/raco pollen render {} \; >~/rendering 2>&1` solved the matter.